# Maintaining unique pages for each domain pointing to same server

Tags: php, .htaccess

Am working on a project that will run for multiple countries.

1. mydomain.com
2. mydomain.co.ke
3. mydomain.co.sa

All the domains are pointing to same file.

My challenge is that i have few pages that should be unique for each country.

Example of such page is the xml feed page

Please how do i achieve that

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions...

Alternative 1 using SetEnv Apache Module:

- All domains should points to same server
- On Apache create a vhost for each domain
- Use [SetEnv](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_env.html) module for set custom env variable, you will set on vhost file
- Apply your business logic based on env country var recovered use [getenv](http://php.net/getenv) function for that

vhost example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   ServerName mydomain.com.br
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/MyDomain

   SetEnv APPLICATION_COUNTRY "brazil"

</VirtualHost>
```

on php:

```
$country = getenv('APPLICATION_COUNTRY');

# your business logic here...
```

Alternative 2 without SetEnv Apache Module:

- All domains should points to same server
- On Apache create a vhost for each domain
- Create a bootstrap.php (entry point) that will figure out country matching $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
- Apply your business logic based on var set

You can start creating an associative array to control custom pages visibility based on country var recovered.